# Add new channel to existing Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I have a 3 organisations hyperledger fabric. I have already created a channel for 3 orgs(all) and network is running. Also smart contract is installed on that channel. Now I want to create 2 more channels in existing network. One for Org1-Org2, second for Org1-Org3. Kindly help me with some documentation or steps to perform operation.

my configtx.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7050

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 9051

    - &Org3
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org3MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org3MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
              Port: 11051


################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
    
        # ACL policy for lscc's "getid" function
        lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getdepspec" function
        lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getccdata" function
        lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL Policy for lscc's "getchaincodes" function
        lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers
        

        #---Query System Chaincode (qscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetChainInfo" function
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
        

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByNumber" function
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's  "GetBlockByHash" function
        qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetTransactionByID" function
        qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByTxID" function
        qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Configuration System Chaincode (cscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigBlock" function
        cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigTree" function
        cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "SimulateConfigTreeUpdate" function
        cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Miscellanesous peer function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for invoking chaincodes on peer
        peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for chaincode to chaincode invocation
        peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Events resource to policy mapping for access control###---#

        # ACL policy for sending block events
        event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for sending filtered block events
        event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # Chaincode Lifecycle Policies introduced in Fabric 2.x
        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "CheckCommitReadiness" function
        _lifecycle/CheckCommitReadiness: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "CommitChaincodeDefinition" function
        _lifecycle/CommitChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for _lifecycle's "QueryChaincodeDefinition" function
        _lifecycle/QueryChaincodeDefinition: /Channel/Application/Readers
    

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    
    # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
    # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
    # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
    # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
    # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050
        - orderer2.example.com:7050
        - orderer3.example.com:7050
        - orderer4.example.com:7050
        - orderer5.example.com:7050

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer2.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer3.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer4.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer5.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I followed below steps base on above file:

- created multihost fabric network using docker swarm,
- created channel configuration in configtx.yaml,
- generated certificates using CA,
- created channel , approved from all Orgs
- installed and queried chaincode
- set up backend server to fetch/update data from network

Answer (score 0):

To create additional channels in your existing `Hyperledger Fabric` network, you can follow these general steps:

1. Create the channel configuration file: You can use the `configtxgen`
   tool to generate a new channel configuration file. You can use the
   existing channel configuration file as a template and modify it to
   include only the organizations you want to include in the new
   channel. For example, to create a channel for `Org1-Org2`, you can
   modify the existing channel configuration file to include only Org1
   and Org2.
2. Create the channel: Once you have the channel configuration file,
   you can create the new channel using the `peer channel create`
   command. You'll need to specify the new channel name, the path to
   the channel configuration file, and the orderer endpoint.
3. Join the peers to the channel: After the channel is created, you'll
   need to join the peers from each organization to the new channel
   using the `peer channel join` command. You'll need to specify the new
   channel name and the address of the peer.
4. Install and instantiate the `chaincode`: Once the peers are joined to
   the new channel, you'll need to install and instantiate the
   `chaincode` on the new channel using the `peer chaincode install` and
   `peer chaincode instantiate` commands.
5. Repeat the process for the second channel: To create the second
   channel for `Org1-Org3`, you can repeat the above steps using a new
   channel configuration file that includes only Org1 and Org3.

For detailed steps and commands, you can refer to the official documentation [Create a channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html) on creating and joining channels.

Note that the specific commands and steps may differ depending on your network setup and configuration.